# My MERN app only works in Chrome. How can I get it to work on all browsers and devices?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, ubuntu, nginx

I have a MERN app with Redux deployed on a Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 18.04 Droplet that should be fully deployed but it only works in my Chrome browser. I think it might only be working because the Chrome browser has a Redux extension, but I don't know.

I have successfully deployed a React app with a back-end similar to this one on a Digital Ocean Droplet but it didn't have MongoDB or Redux. I installed MongoDB and Redux should be installed just fine with everything else, so I don't know what the issue is. Mongo and Redux work just fine when the site is open in the Chrome browser. I bring it up because maybe if you know of a tweak needed when you add Mongo and Redux to an app on a droplet you can just share that info so you don't have to sift through all the data below.

When I visit the site on my iPhone it doesn't display anything.
If I visit the site in Firefox the the favicon for the site loads but the screen is blank. In the console of Firefox I see the error... `Uncaught TypeError: t is undefined`. I don't know where this error is from. I never see it on Chrome when I visit the site.

I don't know if I need to do something different to deploy the app for "production". Maybe this has something to do with the problem.

Maybe the error is something to do with Nginx configuration. This is my Nginx default file...

```
# 159.203.45.100 is where I go to visit the site

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 159.203.45.100;
    root /var/www/MERN_App/client/build;

    error_page 404 /index.html;

    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5002;
    }
}
```

Here is my `server.js` file. (I have pm2 handling it)

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('config')

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/items', require('./routes/api/items'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/comments', require('./routes/api/comments'));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5002;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Here is what `pm2 show 0` displays...

```
    $ pm2 show 0
    Describing process with id 0 - name server 
    ┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ status            │ online                                 │
    │ name              │ server                                 │
    │ namespace         │ default                                │
    │ version           │ 1.0.0                                  │
    │ restarts          │ 0                                      │
    │ uptime            │ 3h                                     │
    │ script path       │ /var/www/MERN_App/server.js            │
    │ script args       │ N/A                                    │
    │ error log path    │ /home/sammy/.pm2/logs/server-error.log │
    │ out log path      │ /home/sammy/.pm2/logs/server-out.log   │
    │ pid path          │ /home/sammy/.pm2/pids/server-0.pid     │
    │ interpreter       │ node                                   │
    │ interpreter args  │ N/A                                    │
    │ script id         │ 0                                      │
    │ exec cwd          │ /var/www/MERN_App                      │
    │ exec mode         │ fork_mode                              │
    │ node.js version   │ 10.22.0                                │
    │ node env          │ N/A                                    │
    │ watch & reload    │ ✘                                      │
    │ unstable restarts │ 0                                      │
    │ created at        │ 2020-08-06T20:33:15.884Z               │
    └───────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
    Revision control metadata 
    ┌──────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ revision control │ git                                            │
    │ remote url       │ https://github.com/MotorCityCobra/MERN_App.git │
    │ repository root  │ /var/www/MERN_App                              │
    │ last update      │ 2020-08-06T20:29:37.883Z                       │
    │ revision         │ 2613e5273955e382a6fd08d023ba1f403d9a3daf       │
    │ comment          │ first commit                                   │
    │ branch           │ master                                         │
    └──────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    Actions available 
    ┌────────────────────────┐
    │ km:heapdump            │
    │ km:cpu:profiling:start │
    │ km:cpu:profiling:stop  │
    │ km:heap:sampling:start │
    │ km:heap:sampling:stop  │
    └────────────────────────┘
    Trigger via: pm2 trigger server <action_name>

    Code metrics value 
    ┌────────────────────────┬───────────┐
    │ Heap Size              │ 33.25 MiB │
    │ Heap Usage             │ 84.57 %   │
    │ Used Heap Size         │ 28.12 MiB │
    │ Active requests        │ 0         │
    │ Active handles         │ 13        │
    │ Event Loop Latency     │ 0.84 ms   │
    │ Event Loop Latency p95 │ 4.93 ms   │
    │ HTTP Mean Latency      │ 30 ms     │
    │ HTTP P95 Latency       │ 57 ms     │
    │ HTTP                   │ 0 req/min │
    └────────────────────────┴───────────┘
    Divergent env variables from local env 
    ┌────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
    │ SSH_CONNECTION │ 75.118.134.38 37152  │
    │ XDG_SESSION_ID │ 23                   │
    │ PWD            │ /var/www/MERN_App    │
    │ SSH_CLIENT     │ 75.118.134.38 37152  │
    │ SSH_TTY        │ /dev/pts/0           │
    └────────────────┴──────────────────────┘

    Add your own code metrics:
    Use `pm2 logs server [--lines 1000]` to display logs
    Use `pm2 env 0` to display environment variables
    Use `pm2 monit` to monitor CPU and Memory usage server
```

Here is my `package.json` for the server...

```
{
  "name": "meme_hole",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "build": "npm install && npm install --prefix client && npm audit fix && npm audit fix --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
    "config": "^3.3.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.22",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^3.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve-index": "^1.9.1",
    "stripe": "^8.81.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }
}
```

My Mongo version...

```
$ mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
{
    "authInfo" : {
        "authenticatedUsers" : [ ],
        "authenticatedUserRoles" : [ ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My Node version is `v10.22.0`

I believe I have installed everything by way of the best practices.
I ran these on the dir the build is in...

```
sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data
sudo chown -R "$USER":www-data /var/www
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0660 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

I followed all the guides Digital Ocean provides to setup the server and everything else.
[Initial Server Setup with Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04)
[How To Install Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)
[How To Install Node.js on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04)
[How to Install MongoDB on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I visited the site in edge, and it didn't work until I installed the extension so you're correct that the extension is making it work. But I got a different error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`. It looks there is a store.js file trying to run `const store = createStore(...` but createStore is undefined.

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/320

Comment: Interesting, @JacobP. I changed `  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` to `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose` in the `store.js` file and now the site is working in Firefox and on my iPhone but NOT in Chrome anymore. Chrome is giving me `Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.`. The errors are completely Greek to me so I'm just going to tinker around with combining && with the new and the old lines I can't make any sense of.

Comment: If you want to write an answer to the question to changing store.js to the effect of adding `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose` to `  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` to make `  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() || window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose));` I'll give you the green check. Otherwise I will answer it myself in a day or so. Thanks. Couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: that's great to hear I'm glad I could help! I'll summarize it all in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I visited the site in edge, and it didn't work until I installed the extension so you're correct that the extension is making it work. But I got a different error, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.` It looks like there is a store.js file trying to run const store = createStore(... but createStore is undefined.

According to this link, https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/320, you can try adding `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose` to your `store.js` file.

If you add it to what you already have you would have this: `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() || window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose));` I guess this makes it run with and without the extension.